# Find out if two rows came from same transaction in Oracle

Tags: oracle, transaction, flashback

I am using Oracle 11.1 and would like to figure out if two rows in one table where inserted by the same transaction.

Is there an easy sql statement to map a row to an transactions id? The table is an insert only table.

What are my options? Some baisc solution would do, I don't really want some extra tool to analyze the log files.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the SCN for a row with the [ORA_ROWSCN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns007.htm#sthref833) pseudocolumn

Unless you have set row-level dependency tracking for the table, this will report the SCN of the last change to the block the row is in, which may not be much use. You can turn on row-level dependency tracking [at `create table`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#CJAEEGDA) time only, so you may need to drop and re-create your table.

Note that row-level tracking increases the size of each row by 6 bytes.

- with rowdependencies:

  ```
  create table foo rowdependencies as
  select level as id from dual connect by level<=10000;

  select count(distinct ora_rowscn) from foo;

  COUNT(DISTINCTORA_ROWSCN) 
  ------------------------- 
  1                         

  begin
    for r in (select id from foo) loop
      update foo set id = id where id=r.id;
      commit;
    end loop;
  end;
  /

  select count(distinct ora_rowscn) from foo;

  COUNT(DISTINCTORA_ROWSCN) 
  ------------------------- 
  10000
  ```
- without rowdependencies (norowdependencies is the default):

  ```
  create table bar as
  select level as id from dual connect by level<=10000;

  select count(distinct ora_rowscn) from bar;

  COUNT(DISTINCTORA_ROWSCN) 
  ------------------------- 
  1                         

  begin
    for r in (select id from bar) loop
      update bar set id = id where id=r.id;
      commit;
    end loop;
  end;
  /

  select count(distinct ora_rowscn) from bar;

  COUNT(DISTINCTORA_ROWSCN) 
  ------------------------- 
  16
  ```

Comment: Just a clarify, a different ORA_ROWSCN on two rows tells me that the two rows where not last changed in the same transaction?

Comment: exactly - ["Oracle Database assigns every committed transaction a unique SCN."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/glossary.htm#CNCPT2120), and with rowdependencies, the SCN of the last transactions on that row is stored with the row (and queried with ora_rowscn)

Comment: Jack Douglas is entirely correct, but just so that it is clear, without row dependencies (the default) rows with the same SCN are not necessarily part of the same transaction.  They may be from separate transactions that are in the same block.  This can be seen in his demonstration by the fact that 10000 update transactions produces only 16 different ora_rowscn values.  Many of the rows from separate transactions share the same ora_rowscn because they are in the same block.

Comment: thanks @Leigh - I realise now I didn't make that too clear in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% reliable way to map rows to transactions, unless you add custom columns.

Using `ORA_ROWSCN`, even with `ROWDEPENDENCIES` enabled, is not always accurate.  Jack's test is correct, and shows that a single transaction will save all rows with the same SCN.  However, it is also possible for a *different* transaction to create a row with the same SCN.

```
--Create a table with ROWDEPENDENCIES enabled.
drop table rowscn_test;
create table rowscn_test(a number) rowdependencies;

--Create 100 jobs to insert and commit one row.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100 loop
        dbms_scheduler.create_job(
            job_name   => 'rowscn_'||i,
            job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action => 'begin insert into rowscn_test values(1); commit; end;',
            enabled    => true
        );
    end loop;
end;
/

--If ORA_ROWSCN was reliable then this query would not return any rows.
select ora_rowscn, count(*)
from rowscn_test
group by ora_rowscn
having count(*) > 1;
```

Sample results:

```
ORA_ROWSCN      COUNT(*)
----------      --------
12124183417057   2
```

The results are not deterministic and will be different for each system.  Sometimes the `ORA_ROWSCN`s are unique and the query returns no results.  But I would not rely on that always being true.